# Ansible: Merge dictionaries within a list adding values to a list

Tags: data-structures, ansible

How can I merge dictionaries within the list with the some properties that are the same and have the values of the properties that are different added to a list value of merged dictionary?

```
[
      {
        "name": "samename",
        "content": "content1"
      },
      {
        "name": "samename",
        "content": "content2"
      },
      {
        "name": "differentname",
        "content": "content3"
      }
    ]
```

Desired output:

```
[
      {
        "name": "samename",
        "content": ["content1", "content2"]
      },
      {
        "name": "differentname",
        "content": "content3"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: please [edit] your question, add the code you have produced so far to attempt to fulfill this requirement and explain which problem your are facing. See [mre]

Comment: Sorry @Zeitounator, I am still new to programming and it was above my level to come up even with an approach to solve it, would have appreciated suggestions where to start from or what Ansible tools to try

Comment: A pretty good central point to start reading about ansible is https://docs.ansible.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data

```yaml
data:
  - content: content1
    name: samename
  - content: content2
    name: samename
  - content: content3
    name: differentname
```

---

Use the filter *json_query* to create lists from the attribute *content*. Then use the filter [*community.general.lists_mergeby*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html#merging-lists-of-dictionaries) to merge the items, e.g.

```yaml
data_groups_query: '[].{name: name, content: [content]}'
data_groups: "{{ [data|json_query(data_groups_query), []]|
                 community.general.lists_mergeby('name', list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
data_groups:
  - content: [content3]
    name: differentname
  - content: [content1, content2]
    name: samename
```

---

(**Update**)

In the next option, use the Jinja filter [*groupby*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby) and create a dictionary

```yaml
data_keys: "{{ data|groupby('name')|map(attribute='0') }}"
data_vals: "{{ data|groupby('name')|map(attribute='1')|
                                    map('map', attribute='content') }}"
data_groups_dict: "{{ dict(data_keys|zip(data_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
data_groups_dict:
  differentname: [content3]
  samename: [content1, content2]
```

Convert the dictionary to a list

```yaml
data_groups: "{{ data_groups_dict|dict2items(key_name='name',
                                             value_name='content') }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
data_groups:
  - content: [content3]
    name: differentname
  - content: [content1, content2]
    name: samename
```